# I try to make a new set that it find the elements common between the two sets and subtract them with for and if without using different set method

Tags: python-3.x, list, indexing, range

I try to make a new set that it find the elements common between the two sets and subtract them with for and if without using different set method

I was going to compare all the elements in my first set and second set by opening two different for loops and using if command, find the common ones and remove them with the remove command, but I am getting the "list index out of range" error

my code is below. I don't know much coding as I am beginner. I wrote this code for practice

```
my_set = {1,2,3,4,5}
your_set = {4,5,6,7,8,9,10}

my_list = list(my_set)
your_list = list(your_set)

for i in range(len(my_list)):
    for j in range(len(your_list)):
        if (my_list[i] == your_list[j]):
            my_list.remove(my_list[i])

my_set2 = set(my_list)
print(my_set2)
```

Comment: As you're referring to a specific error message, it seems like you already have something implemented in a specific programming language. It seems like the iteration is incorrect and iterates beyond the end of the container. Best add some code to your question and tag it with the appropriate programming language tag.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that . I made a mistake because it's my first post

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, do you want to remove the common items in `my_set` and `your_set` from `my_set`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the common items in `my_set` and `your_set` from `my_set`.

```py
my_set = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
your_set = {4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}

new_set = my_set.difference(your_set.intersection(my_set))
print(new_set)
print(my_set) 

# {1, 2, 3}
# {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

If you want the difference removed from `your_set`,

```py
your_new_set = your_set.difference(your_set.intersection(my_set))
```

---

You can also do it using `if` and `for` as in your original code,

```py
result = []  # Initialize an empty list to store the result

# Iterate through each element in my_set
for i in my_set:
    # Check if the current element is not in your_set
    if i not in your_set:
        # If it is not, append it to the result list
        result.append(i)

# if you want output in set, convert the list back to set
result = set(result)

# Print the final result
print(result)
```